# Tensorflow, difference between tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits and tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits

Tags: tensorflow

I have read the [docs of both functions](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/nn/classification), but as far as I know, for function `tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits, labels, dim=-1, name=None)`, the result is the cross entropy loss, in which the dimensions of `logits` and `labels` are the same.

But, for function `tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits`, the dimensions of `logits` and `labels` are not the same?

Could you give a more detail example of `tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The difference is that `tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits` doesn't assume that the classes are mutually exclusive:

> Measures the probability error in discrete classification tasks in
>   which each class is independent and not mutually exclusive. For
>   instance, one could perform multilabel classification where a picture
>   can contain both an elephant and a dog at the same time.

Compare with `sparse_*`:

> Measures the probability error in discrete classification tasks in
>   which the classes are mutually exclusive (each entry is in exactly one
>   class). For example, each CIFAR-10 image is labeled with one and only
>   one label: an image can be a dog or a truck, but not both.

As such, with sparse functions, the dimensions of `logits` and `labels` are not the same: `labels` contain one number per example, whereas `logits` the number of classes per example, denoting probabilities.

Comment: At least in the newest version of TensorFlow 1.2 the above description of `softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits` is no longer true:  '... in which the classes are mutually exclusive (each entry is in exactly one class)...' https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits